# Gstreamer pipeline fails to run with osxaudiosrc plugin

Tags: gstreamer, macos-catalina, gstreamer-1.0

I am running below pipeline on mac but it shows error while running:

```
$**gst-launch-1.0 osxaudiosrc device=92**  
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...  
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...  
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...  
0:00:00.048601000 16777 0x7fafe585d980 WARN                osxaudio gstosxcoreaudio.c:500:gst_core_audio_asbd_to_caps: No sample rate  
0:00:00.048699000 16777 0x7fafe585d980 ERROR             audio-info audio-info.c:304:gboolean gst_audio_info_from_caps(GstAudioInfo *, const GstCaps *): no channel-mask property given  
0:00:00.048736000 16777 0x7fafe585d980 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *):<osxaudiosrc0> error: Internal data stream error.  
0:00:00.048744000 16777 0x7fafe585d980 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072:void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *):<osxaudiosrc0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)  
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock  
**ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOsxAudioSrc:osxaudiosrc0: Internal data stream error.**    
Additional debug info:  
gstbasesrc.c(3072): void gst_base_src_loop(GstPad *) ():
 /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOsxAudioSrc:osxaudiosrc0:  
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)  
Execution ended after 0:00:00.000101000  
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...  
Setting pipeline to READY ...  
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
```

The device id mentioned in the cmd is fetched from gst-inspect and is of macbook speakers. I am using GStreamer 1.16.2 on catalina.
What is wrong/missing in this pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you have an incomplete pipeline.

Once the `osxaudiosrc` starts producing buffers, where is it supposed to go? Do you want to encode it and/or write it to file? Should it be streamed somewhere? Should it be plotted? ...

This is also the reason GStreamer is erroring out. There's no element after your source element, so *if* it were to start playing, those buffers would somehow end up in the void, with no destination to go to (to be a bit more thorough: you're trying to push data on a pad which has no peer, so it would try to dereference an invalid sinkpad). Since this is not possibe, GStreamer just plainly stops.

An example pipeline is given in the [osxaudiosrc documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-osxaudiosrc.html):

```
gst-launch-1.0 osxaudiosrc ! wavenc ! filesink location=audio.wav
```